# Drupal subscription membership with PayPal

Tags: payment-gateways

I am trying to create a website which contains some premium content - What I need is when the user clicks on a subscribe button - he is redirected to the PayPal payment gateway - once his payment is accepted I want a "premium" role that I had previously created to get assigned to that user.

I used the [paypal roles](https://www.drupal.org/project/paypal_roles) module - which seems tailor made for this. However, on returning from the PayPal payment form, the new role is not assigned to the user. Any suggestions with regards to how to solve this issue with this module or any other solution to implement the same?

Comment: do you get any errors in the log?

Comment: Can you try commerce_license https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license, It's created for that.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. No I did not get any error messages in the log. I also do not get any empty array when I try to access the paypal listener on my site from an incognito window. @murad - tried uber cart , will now give commerce a shot. thanks!